# How to save the current state of an object as file and retrieve the same when needed?

Tags: java

Actually I wanted to store the current state of my object (its position its listeners,its stylings and all other properties) as a file and retrieve the same whenever needed. For the above I first serialized a button and then deserialized it. But on deserialization the button lost all its event listeners. Is there any other alternative for doing the same ?

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                         
  System.out.println("hello world");
}                                        
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                         
 try {
    f2.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(f2);
    ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(c);
    oos.flush();
    System.out.println("done");
    cont.remove(jButton2);//serializing above jButton2
    oos.close();
} 
  catch (Exception ex) 
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}     
}                                        
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                         
  FileInputStream fis;
  JButton b;
 try {
    fis = new FileInputStream("nnn.java");
    ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    b=(JButton)ois.readObject();
    bg.add(b);
    bg.revalidate();
    bg.repaint();
      }
   catch (Exception ex) 
   {
   System.err.println("error");
   }       
}
```

Comment: above bg is  a panel to which i am adding the deserialized button b

Comment: what is `c` in `oos.writeObject(c);`

Comment: You say "on deserialization the button lost its onclick events and all" - what is all?? what got lost?? you should know that serialization only saves an Onject state (variable contents) not its class (where methods and logic resides)

Comment: I just meant the event listener.@Sharon

Comment: c is the component to which I assigned the instance of jButton2 the button which I serialized and deserialized @Sharon Ben

Comment: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/developing-java-beans/1565922891/ch05s05.html - Try this.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably meant "button lost it's listeners", right?

Something like this:

```
JButton jButton = new JButton();
jButton.addActionListener(e -> {
    System.out.println("Event: " + e);
});
```

The problem is that [JButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) (its predecessor [AbstractButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html)) uses [EventListenerList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html) class to store listeners. The list class has field listenerList which is marked as **transient**.

```
protected transient Object[] listenerList = ...
```

Transient fields are not serialised.

I think solution here is to repopulate listeners of the button after deserialisation.

```
JButton jButton = deserializeButton();
createButtonListeners().forEach(listener -> jButton.addActionListener(listener));
```

Comment: can you tell me if i could just remove the transient from listenerList. If it could solve my problem.

Comment: I don't think so. EventListenerList is a standard Java class, so you cannot modify it. You would have to implement your own listener handling in JButton and I don't think that would be reliable solution or worth it. Second thing is, there is a reason why the field is transient (probably). I wouldn't try to bend this functionality. I think repopulating the listeners on object deserialisation is the way to go.